# CKEditor placeholder angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, ckeditor, placeholder

i've got some troubles with ng2-ckeditor, I need to put placeholder on it, but I dont really know how to do this in angular 2

```
 <ckeditor
            [config]="config"
            [(ngModel)]="text"
            [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"
            (change)="updateRemainingCharacters()"
 >
 </ckeditor>
```

Is there solution for that using config? I tried

```
    this.config.placeholder = 'some value';
```

but it doesn't work

Comment: Look at this post, where a full example is provided as well in the linked library : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46119865/angular-4-add-ckeditor-to-component-ts?noredirect=1#comment79205692_46119865

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you can add `placeholder` in `CKEditor-5`

```
  <ckeditor [config]="{ placeholder:'Placeholder Text', toolbar: [ 'bold', 'italic', 'bulletedList' ] }">
  </ckeditor>
```

[See docs](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/integration/frameworks/angular.html#setting-the-placeholder)

Answer (score 0):

Add JS:

```
<script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.5.11/full-all/ckeditor.js"></script>
```

Here add **`extraPlugins:'placeholder' in [config]`**

```
<ckeditor
  [(ngModel)]="text"
  [config]="{extraPlugins:'placeholder'}">
</ckeditor>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, for response, but it doesn't work do you know maybe how to define any text in this placeholder and add placeholder with other configurations ?

Comment: Ok, it was some missunderstanding I need to include something like placeholder in common input something like 'put text here...' which disappear any time I put any text on that

Comment: I think it will help to you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28301703/how-do-i-add-a-placeholder-attribute-to-an-instance-of-ckeditor